# If i run a method from inside a method, do they run concurrently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My question is this:

I call on this method from my controller,

```
def METHOD_1
 do something 
 EXECUTE METHOD_2
 do something more
 do something more
 do something more
 do something more
end
```

Now will it execute and finish METHOD_2 before it continues with the "do something more" or will the two methods then run concurrently

Comment: As you have written it, `do something more` will only run once `EXECUTE METHOD_2` has returned.

Comment: As @jvillian said. But if you want to experience full _joy_ of asynchronicity, go to node.js or other evented environment. :)

Comment: Or, possibly, use background jobs, no? Although, formally, I suppose even with a background job, `EXECUTE METHOD_2` is still returning before `do something more` proceeds.

Comment: @jvillian: or that, yes. Depends on whether he wants to return values and how/where. :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies, i actually need method 2 to finish before it continues so thats what i needed to know thanks... @jvillian can you answer so i mark answered?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "finish". The next line is executed as soon as `METHOD_2` _returns_. But that doesn't prevent `METHOD_2` from starting a thread or process which might still run when it returns. Maybe you should be more specific – what's the actual method that you are worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written it, do `something more` will only run once `EXECUTE METHOD_2` has returned.

See original question for additional comments...